# OpenGL my Texture is appearing as a single color?

Tags: c++, opengl

OpenGL my Texture is appearing as a single color. Try different texture only come out as a single from the texture. If texture is majority green then the output is green.

My Texture class

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string& FilePath)
    {
        this->RenderID = 0;
        this->FilePath = FilePath;
        this->localBuffer = nullptr;
        this->width = 0;
        this->height = 0;
        this->BPP = 0;

        stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
        localBuffer = stbi_load(this->FilePath.c_str(), &width, &height, &BPP, 4);

        glGenTextures(1, &RenderID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, RenderID);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


        if (localBuffer)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, localBuffer);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "error damn it";
        }

        unbind();

        stbi_image_free(localBuffer);
    }
```

My main loop

```
while (!window.isClosed())
{
    window.clear();
    render.Draw(vao, ibo, shade);
    texture.bind();
    shade.setUniform1i("u_texture", 0);
    window.update();
}
```

Fragment Shader :

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 tex_out;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main()
{
    vec4 tex = texture(u_texture , tex_out);
    FragColor = tex;
 }
```

Texture used :

[image: Texture Used]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Your model is most likely missing texture coordinates.

Comment: No the texture coordinates are there

Comment: Then you might have an error in your code that binds them to shader variables. Or the vertex shader does not pass them through. Try to output the texture coordinates directly from the fragment shader and you will see if this is the problem.

Comment: At least you have to show how the `vao` is specified, to make the question [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Shouldn't the binding of the texture (`texture.bind();`) be before the drawing of the geometry (`render.Draw(vao, ibo, shade);`)?

Comment: Error was in my GL vertex attributes pointer I forgot to multiple the pointer with the size of the type of data